# Stop the rounding on float c++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am getting an issue when trying to output my float using std::cout <<

I have the following values:

```
 vector2f = {-32.00234098f, 96.129380f} //takes 2 floats (x, y)
 output: -32.0023:96.1294
```

What I am looking for is:

```
 output: -32.00234098:96.129380
```

The actual numbers could be vary from the 7 decimal places (.0000007) to 3 decimal places (.003) so setting a fixed rounding number does not work in this case.

Any help would be great as I have tried changed to doubles as well but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use the `std::fixed` output manipulator. (And possibly the `std:setprecision()` manipulator too.)

Comment: Even with the fixed it is still rounding the number at the end and can't use the std::setprecision() method

Comment: `float` is only accurate to about 7 decimal digits not 7 decimal places.  Your required output is 10 and 8 digits respectively so there will be rounding/inaccuracy.

Comment: Perhaps use `long double`, it has more decimal digits than `float` and `double`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. you need to include `<iomanip>` and use the `std::setprecision` manipulator.
2. To get the level of accuracy you want you will need to use `double`s rather than `float`s.

e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    auto x = -32.00234098f, y = 96.129380f;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << std::fixed << x << ":" << y << std::endl;

    // doubles    
    auto a = -32.00234098, b = 96.129380;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << std::fixed << a << ":" << b << std::endl;

}
```

example output:

```
-32.00234222:96.12937927
-32.00234098:96.12938000
```

Comment: I was wanting to avoid using the <iomanip> header but it appears I need to use it for the case of getting extensive accuracy beyond the decimal point. Thanks!

Comment: this example still rounds the decimal part if the precision number is less than the available decimal. Try this for example: ```double a=2.003943; std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << a << std::endl; ```outputs ```2.004```instead of  ```2.003```. But I want is ```2.003```. Is there any way to achieve this in cpp without implementing the function yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the output precision of the stream using `std::precision` manipulator.

To print trailing zeroes up to the given precision like in your example output, you need to use `std::fixed` manipulator.